# What do the initial cell divisions look like in bird embryogenesis?

Tags: reproduction

The germ disc in a bird (a disc because its a chordate) is a mystery to me. The ovum (yolk) is a huge mass of nutrients. It then gets impregnated. Then, what? What does the initial cell divisions look like (they can't be symmetrical since yolk is clearly pushed to one end of the whole thing. )

Comment: I'm pretty certain the ovum isn't the yolk. Ova are way smaller than that. Human embryos also have a yolk sac, and it develops during early embryonic development. According to wikipedia, in birds it's a specialized structure made in the mother's body and is part of the ovum in very small animals like some fishes or invertebrates, not birds.

Comment: I'm just interested in what is true. I've kept hearing the meme that the yolk in birds is a single cell, and it looks plausible but always sounded a bit weird. The human yolk sac isn't homologous with birds yolk sac, at all. It develops from the germ disc long after fertilization during the formation of the gut tube. Overall phylotypical stages in embryogenesis are hard to master because there is so much variation, one thing that looks identical is achieved by a completely different procedure, is common.

Comment: The yolk of birds may well be a single cell, but it doesn't mean that cell is the ovum. (actually I read down the wikipedia page, and it has a section on chicken eggs that explicitly says the claim you're describing is false "in strict sense". I know I know, wikipedia, there's a reason this is a comment and not an answer, but the citations might be useful). I didn't know the human yolk sac wasn't homologous to other yolk structures, thanks for that!

Comment: Overall, how the embryo gets to different stages differs a lot while the stages look the same. It's pretty confusing until you get that the processes aren't homologous. The mammal yolk sac is a part of the gut tube, it forms as the initial germ disc (that exists to conform to notochord organizational axis) bends into a cylinder.

Comment: Looking at [this diagram](http://www.mun.ca/biology/desmid/brian/BIOL3530/DEVO_03/ch03f13.jpg) and [this one](http://www.mun.ca/biology/desmid/brian/BIOL3530/DEVO_03/ch03f15.jpg) from [this page](http://www.mun.ca/biology/desmid/brian/BIOL3530/DEVO_03/devo_03.html), it looks like a small portion of the edge of the yolk develop a "cleavage furrow" which then develops into a multi-celled "blastodisc" or "blastoderm" that becomes a more differentiated embryo.

Comment: @Hypnosifl still a bit of a mystery. Since the unit those processes deal with are cells, if the yolk to begin is a single cell, the ovum, assuming the initial cell divisions are normal mitosis, doubling number of cells, is it originally undergoing an asymmetrical division where one cell takes the entire yolk and the other forms at one pole, and, does that other pole cell then continue from there to form the germ disc and all that?

Comment: [This page](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/Book%3A_Biology_(Kimball)/14%3A_Embryonic_Development_and_its_Regulation/14.03%3A_Cleavage) also says that "The hen's egg consists of just a tiny patch of cytoplasm resting on the surface of a large ball of yolk" and that the initial cells during cell division have a plasma membrane on top and sides but not on the bottom, where "the bottom of the cell [meaning the cytoplasm I guess] is in direct contact with the yolk". Calls this "meroblastic cleavage", might google that term to find out more.

Comment: @Hypnosifl You should write that as an answer. I think using the contrast with frog development (where the yolk is more... 'intracellular') is probably also quite informative.

Comment: @Hypnosifl that sounds a bit contradictory, if the tiny patch of cytoplasm is continuous with the yolk, isn't it a single cell. Or do two cells partially fuse in the ovary?

Comment: @BryanKrause Do you know if the yolk is the same cell as the ovum and a single cell?

Comment: @IanMalcolm It is not controversial that there is one and only one cell present before post-fertilization devisions (which occur before the full egg is developed). What is a bit unclear is what you call a "single cell" after that in the early stages of development. I'm not an avian development (or any development) expert and people tend to pick up chickens as model organisms after the first day or so after many many cell divisions (frogs are much nicer models for the first few divisions), so the earliest steps of avian development are often left out of textbooks.

Comment: What I call a "single cell" is what you call "not controversial that there is only one cell present". No need to misrepresent my statements. @Oosaka thought the ovum and yolk were different cells (easy to think since the yolk is huge), I've heard that they're a single cell, although it is a bit counter-intuitive, but there are other examples of huge single celled structures. Main question is how that huge single cell does the initial cell divisions.

Comment: @IanMalcolm You can call that a single cell, but there is a lot of non-cellular material in a living organism as well. The majority of the yolk is kind of...in between. Hence the potential for controversy. "There is one cell" is not the same as "This is all one cell". Hypnosifl gave the answer already to "how that huge single cell does the initial cell divisions", though in a comment that should be an answer.

Comment: You call it "not controversial that there is only one cell present". If the material of the yolk is intracellular, is it not misrepresentative to point out that living organisms can have non-cellular (extra-cellular) material?

Comment: That's just it...it's kind of intracellular, kind of not. There isn't a lipid bilayer there from what I can tell, but it's also definitely segregated from the cytoplasm part of the ovum. It's also all material that originated in other cells.

Comment: @Bryan Krause - If you want to give an answer that repeats the points (or specific links) I mentioned in my comments go for it, I just found this much by googling and don't really feel I know enough to comment on the issue Ian Malcolm is interested in about whether the yolk itself would be considered a giant cell or more like "cell + giant blob of nutrients attached", I suppose this would depend on what definition of "cell" is most commonly used by biologists.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Alright, I'll take a stab at it later.

Comment: The point here is mostly that the yolk is often said to be a huge single cell. If its just material deposited by cells lining the follicles, then, it's clearly not a cell but extracellular, and the ovum is just enclosed in it. Grau and Wilson said so here, they also mention that most people believe the yolk is a cell. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02146023

Answer (score 1):

This is covered well in almost any text that talks of early embryonic development in birds. Basically, the cleavage divisions look roughly symmetrical if you look *end-on* from the animal pole. But, as mentioned in the question, the process is quite asymmetrical *in profile*, with the blastoderm being at one end and the huge yolk occupying the other.

The yolk later gets invested by a layer of cells (the splanchnopleure) to form the yolk sac while the blastoderm forms the embryo proper.

You could see [this page](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Book_-_The_Early_Embryology_of_the_Chick_3) for more details. (Not just this page, this site in general is an excellent resource for learning embryology.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on the false belief that the ovum contains the yolk as a single cell. This is a belief that is very common, and often spread in the literature. Grau and Wilson said in 1963 in [Avian Oogenesis and Yolk Deposition](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02146023): *The yolk of the hen's egg is often given as an example of a huge cell containing a food supply for the developing chick embryo. Current views hold that oocytes grow by removing nutrients from the blood and the follicle cells which surround them. Thus yolk deposition is thought of as primarily an intracellular phenomenon. We believe that this viewpoint is inadequate, and wish to propose the following alternative hypothesis.*

Of course, if the yolk is not *inside* the ovum, then there is no mystery to the early cell divisions.

Comment: Hi, it's me, the person telling you the bird yolk isn't the ovum! I told you wikipedia confirmed, and I let it at that initially because it was just a comment, I didn't feel the need to do deep research, but I saw the question continued to spark debate so I actually went to look at wikipedia's sources. And from what I was able to read of "Atlas of chick development", a 2005 book, I'm thinking... the wikipedia page was maybe wrong and you were right all along? But also, the book is detailed enough (and chapters free to read on google books) that it might answer your questions regardless.

Comment: https://books.google.fr/books?id=JAjGAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&hl=fr&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: The yolk is both part of the oocyte and yet separate from the cytosol of the cell including the nucleus, mitochondria, and all the other normal cellular stuff. Grau and Wilson are merely arguing (without much evidence) that the oocyte doesn't play much of an active role in growing itself.

Comment: @Oosaka You were probably right, I always thought the claim that the yolk was a single cell seemed wrong. But it seems like a very common myth, myths are good at capturing attention so it took me a while to get that the yolk is extracellular and secreted by cells surrounding follicle lumen. That's what Grau and Wilson said, seem as credible as anyone else, and it fits with my own reasoning.

Comment: Bryan Krause opinion differs from Grau and Wilson. I think they seem credible, if anyone has strong evidence or indisputable evidence that they are wrong, feel free to present it in comment. If anyone has better answer, feel free to produce a separate answer.

Comment: To be supportive of differing opinions, here is the credentials of the author I cite, so that anyone may discredit his claim: Charles Richard Grau, Professor of Avian Sciences, Emeritus. https://senate.universityofcalifornia.edu/_files/inmemoriam/html/CharlesRichardGrau.htm

His claim supports Oosaka's initial comment, thanks for all comments and for making me understand what I wondered about. Everyone contributed to my understanding. It was also what my intuition was, but for some reason I trusted the popular myth. Shame on me.

Comment: @IanMalcolm Grau's credentials are great but that book being from 1963 less so; it's why I pointed out "Atlas of Chick development" being from 2005. I don't know if the sources actually disagree though, I would have to see what both say.

Comment: false. scientific theory does not disprove itself as a factor of time. most current scientific theory that still holds as fundaments much older than 1963, lots of good work from around that time as well. your initial comment was beneficial. anyone who has strong evidence Grau and Wilson were wrong may publish an answer.

Comment: @IanMalcolm Grau and Wilson are not claiming to *prove* anything, and they show no data. They're just publishing a hypothesis to motivate research. Their paper has only been cited a couple of times and none of those citations provide evidence for their hypothesis. The quote is from what is effectively a "letter to the editor" rather than a scientific paper.

Comment: Feel free to produce an answer that is the most accurate you can conceive of. That yolk is extracellular (see my answer, or your own comment, "a lot of non-cellular material in a living organism as well") resolves issue in initial cell divisions. If superior answer is provided, not a problem.

Comment: @IanMalcolm Um... scientific theories *that are correct* do not disprove themselves as a matter of time, no, but not all scientific theories are correct, if they were science would be finished. Plenty of old scientific papers still hold up, but when they do then the more recent review/consensus documents agree with them. "More recent sources are more likely to be more accurate" is a completely correct rule of thumb for figuring out what science says about a question.

Comment: @Oosaka I don't think you and I disagree. Anyone with an open mind understands that "if they were science would be finished", the problem is status quo bias, so many people lack an open mind. "scientism" is the belief that the present social agreement of what the world is, is somehow the perfect world view and the scientific process end state. This forum is not very open minded, so I see no benefit to you and me "debating", debate is just a fallacy based on instincts monkeys have to fight over territory, with ideas irrelevant but our monkey brains do not get that.

Comment: I'd be open to chatting over some other medium, but in this forum, I just wanted to sort out what I wondered about. Peace.